# one adapter fot 2 recycleviews

Tags: java, android-studio

Is it possible to have one adapter for 2 recycleviews ?
I've tried to do so but after I get out from an activity and return my recycleview is become empty

This is my adapter :

```java
public class MyRecipeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecipeAdapter.RecipeHolder> {

    ArrayList <Recipe> list_of_recipe;
    Context context;

    public MyRecipeAdapter (Context context ,   ArrayList <Recipe>list_of_recipe){
        this.context = context ;
        this.list_of_recipe = list_of_recipe ;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyRecipeAdapter.RecipeHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_recipe_tap,parent,false);
        //holder will take the info put it in the item layout
        RecipeHolder holder = new RecipeHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @SuppressLint("RecyclerView")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyRecipeAdapter.RecipeHolder holder, int position) {
        Recipe recipe = list_of_recipe.get(position);
        holder.recipename.setText(recipe.getRecipe_name());

        Picasso.get().load(recipe.getImage()).into(holder.recipeImage);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String id = list_of_recipe.get(position).getRecipe_id();

                Intent intent = new Intent(context,RecipePage.class);
                intent.putExtra("recipe_id_home",id);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list_of_recipe.size();
    }



    public class RecipeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView recipeImage;
        TextView recipename;
        RelativeLayout recipe_parent ;

        public RecipeHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            recipe_parent = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_parent);
            recipeImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            recipename = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        }
    }
}
```

and I user it twice in 2 different fragments each fragment has a recycleview and I want both of them to show same layout inflated in the adapter `R.layout.single_recipe_tap`.

This is the first fragment :

```java
    //retriving user recipes
        data_ref_recipe = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Recipes");
        Query query = data_ref_recipe.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(current_uid);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {

                    for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Recipe recipe = data.getValue(Recipe.class);
                        recipe_list.add(recipe);
                    }
                    newAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });



        GridLayoutManager gridnewManager = new GridLayoutManager(this.getContext(),3);
        myrecipe_cycle.setLayoutManager(gridnewManager); // set LayoutManager to RecyclerView
        //create the adapter
        newAdapter = new MyRecipeAdapter(this.getContext(), recipe_list);
        myrecipe_cycle.setAdapter(newAdapter); // set the Adapter to RecyclerView
```

And this is the second fragment :

```java
    newAdapter = new MyRecipeAdapter(this.getContext(),recipe_list);
        saved_recycle.setAdapter(newAdapter); // set the Adapter to RecyclerView

        GridLayoutManager gridnewManager = new GridLayoutManager(this.getContext(),3);
        saved_recycle.setLayoutManager(gridnewManager); // set LayoutManager to RecyclerView

        user_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(current_uid).child("Saved Recipes");
        user_ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                if (snapshot.exists()){

                    for(DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()){

                        //retrive id of recipe
                        String id = data.getValue(String.class);

                        //retrive recipe obj
                        recipe_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Recipes").child(id);
                        recipe_ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                                Recipe recipe = snapshot.getValue(Recipe.class);
                                recipe_list.add(0, recipe); //0 to put data in first not buttom

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                            }
}); } newAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
```

Comment: Please, show your code if it’s possible

Comment: @tornadoradon
 i've add the rquired code